# Remove Leading 0s in a row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I had a DataFrame (df) like this:

```
    A       B       C       D
0  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.1234
1  0.0000 -0.9760 -0.5268 -0.4261
2 -0.6277 -1.9284 -1.7718  3.4021
3  0.0000  0.0000 -0.0013  2.2955
4  0.6241 -1.9643 -0.6090  2.0827
```

and I wanted to remove the leading 0.0000s from each row and have NaN as the white space behind the new 'calibrated' row like this:

```
    A       B       C       D
0  0.1234  NaN     NaN     NaN   
1 -0.9760 -0.5268 -0.4261  NaN   
2 -0.6277 -1.9284 -1.7718  3.4021
3 -0.0013  2.2955  NaN     NaN   
4  0.6241 -1.9643 -0.6090  2.0827
```

Is there a simple pandas function to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let use `mask`, `eq`, `apply`, and `dropna`:

```
df.mask(df.eq(0)).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values,index=x.index[:len(x.dropna())]),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        A       B       C       D
0  0.1234     NaN     NaN     NaN
1 -0.9760 -0.5268 -0.4261     NaN
2 -0.6277 -1.9284 -1.7718  3.4021
3 -0.0013  2.2955     NaN     NaN
4  0.6241 -1.9643 -0.6090  2.0827
```